# How to pass string variables to JObject C# - Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json.net

Good day, I need to assign variables to `JObject`:

```
JObject json = JObject.Parse(@"{
RequestData: {
  AccountCredential: {
    AccountLink: 'dFyRCVYNM0aGb1LSR/0B8e+eSVr1Zf1xj9YHmMVoiZWk28XtWEyIxEbGXnr1EdvS+QBPzjweau7tbf5QlDv97IQ2jwfUB=='
  },
  AccountNumber: '000011887755',
  BookingDateStart: '2022-07',
  BookingDateEnd: '2022-07'
}  }");
```

I want to pass values ​​to `AccountLink`, `AccountNumber`, `BookingDateStart`, `BookingDateEnd`. If you notice, I set the values ​​to hard, but these change, where I should use it by passing the parameters.

I have tried to use the `JsonSerializerOptions`, but I get an error

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Json'

I want to be able to use it in an asynchronous task.

Does anyone have any ideas? Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two major C# JSON libraries: `Newtonsoft.Json` and `System.Text.Json`. `JObject` is a class from the former, and `JsonSerializerOptions` is a class from the latter. You can't just mix them together. If you want to modify Newtonsoft.Json serialization, you need to look up how to do that in Netwonsoft.Json.

---

That having been said, you don't *need* a serializer for what you are trying to do. Creating a `JObject` from variable data is simple in Netwonsoft.Json. Your code would look similar to that ([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ze9wFi)):

```
    var json = new JObject(
        new JProperty("RequestData",
            new JObject(
                new JProperty("AccountCredential", 
                    new JObject(
                        new JProperty("AccountLink", "...")
                    )
                ),
                new JProperty("AccountNumber", "..."),
                new JProperty("BookingDateStart", "..."),
                new JProperty("BookingDateEnd", "...")
            )
        )
    );
```

Just replace "..." with the value you want to fill your JObject with.